# Reusing StringBuilder or creating a new one?

Tags: java, optimization, performance, strings, android

Given that it is better to reuse objects than create new ones when developing with Android, is it worth while deleting the contents of a `StringBuilder` and reusing it?

```java
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
//build up a string
b.delete(0, b.length());
//reuse it
```

Compared to:

```java
StringBuilder b1 = new StringBuilder();
//build up a string
StringBuilder b2 = new StringBuilder();
//create a new one
```

Comment: Is this even worth thinking about as long as it is not in a very tight loop?

Comment: @Bobby - I have about a dozen separate strings of different sizes I need to build up in the one class, some in a loop, some not. Was not sure if it was worth while so that's why I am asking :)

Comment: No, I meant this smells a lot like premature optimization. If you start worrying about "a dozen strings which need to be concatenated" without *any* profiling, then you've a knot in your brain. And I didn't mean that as an insult but as a heart-warm warning...been there, done that. Rule of thumb: If you concatenate strings in a loop, use a StringBuilder. Second rule of thumb: If you worry about speed, profile first.

Comment: No insult taken and point noted. Truthfully, I am not overly concerned about optimization and I am an inexperienced programmer (or could you tell). I simply wanted to know if this would improved performance in some small way. Given that there is no .clear() method for StringBuilders, I half expected some one to say that iterating through the buffer to wipes it's contents is actually more expensive than garbage collecting. Never ask, never know.

Comment: That's absolutely true. I think the difference between the two are not only small, but *hardly noticeable*. I just wanted to make sure that you understand that this question is hardly about real-world optimization

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reusing doesn't need memory allocation, so it could be faster as *@Mike Nakis* mentioned. On the other hand it leads to ugly code: you use the same variable for two (or more) different purposes which could confuse readers, make maintenance harder. Unless you have a good reason to do that avoid it. I mean, you have a good reason if a profiling shows that creating new `StringBuilder` instances is a bottleneck in the application.

If you really have to reuse `StringBuilder`s, try accessing them with different names with a helper method:

```
public static StringBuilder reuseForBetterPerformance(final StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    return sb;
}
```

Client code:

```
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
//build up a string
final StringBuilder c = reuseForBetterPerformance(b);
//reuse it
c.append(...)
```

It makes the code a little bit more readable, since the method name says why you're reusing the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of final

Comment: If it wasn't made final then you could create a new one return it, but we want to return the same object but emptied.

Comment: `final` helps readers, because they know that the reference always points to the same instance and it doesn't change later. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/why-declare-final-variables-inside-methods but you can find other questions on Programmers.SE in the topic.

Comment: That helper function is an excellent compromise. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 14):

To add some hard numbers, I wrote a simple test application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int iterations = 1000000;
    int secondIterations = 25;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int count = 0; count < iterations; count++) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int secondCounter = 0; secondCounter < secondIterations; secondCounter++) {
            builder.append("aaassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Recreation took: " + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int count = 0; count < iterations; count++) {
        builder.delete(0, builder.length());
        for (int secondCounter = 0; secondCounter < secondIterations; secondCounter++) {
            builder.append("aaassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Reuse took: " + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Recreation took: 10594ms
Reuse took: 1937ms
```

So, yes, as it seems reusing is indeed faster, at least if you test it in a tight loop with a small memory footprint. But please keep in mind that those numbers were generated by using **1 million** iterations.

Keep two rules in mind:

- First go for readability and maintainability.
- Second...run a profiler.

This difference I see here is nothing I'd worry about until I really run into performance problems.

Comment: Wow, that's 5 times faster.  Though I would be willing to bet that most of this difference is due to the fact that your "recreation" loop generates 2.2 gigabytes of garbage, so exercises the garbage collector, (to its detriment,) while the "reuse" loop produces a lot less garbage, close to nothing.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, of course it is worthwhile, even in the great big world outside of Android.

According to [the documentation about `StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

> Every string builder has a capacity. As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string builder does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger.

This means that deletion of the `StringBuilder`'s contents will result in no memory allocation operation for its internal array of `char`s (it will just set its length to zero and return, maintaining its last capacity). Plus, you save the `StringBuilder` object itself.

Comment: thanks ur reply is very helpful for me ,so here i have some question that  1. what is the default capacity of string builder. 2. so what if StringBuilder dynamically resize its buffer that time it will allocate a new memory please confirm.

Comment: The default initial capacity is 16, but you can set it to whatever you want when invoking the StringBuilder's constructor.  Saying that the StringBuilder will dynamically resize its buffer is equivalent to saying that the StringBuilder will allocate new memory.